# HTTP Cookies: Can I Set Expiry as Epoch Millis?

Tags: http, cookies

I am working on a little cookie library for a login project I'm working on.  Usually expiration is set in thew syntax:

```
 Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

I am wondering, what are the rules on this syntax?  Can I put an epoch time milliseconds in there instead to save some of the coding work?

```
 Expires=1384303547538
```

When I read about web standards this is almost never mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should read the relevant spec, in this case the Cookie RFC: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6265.html#rfc.section.4.1.1.

Comment: Correction, RFC 2616.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.3.1.  The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in RFC 2616.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1.  The answer is no.